# jQuery touch links not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have some links that are not working on our mobile view of our site. All our site is doing is showing the mobile version if the path in the domain has /m in it. Everything seems to be working fine except for these 2 links:

```
<ol>
 <li>
  <a id="turn_off_mobile_link" href="http://oursite.com/welcome.htm?mobile_view_turn_off=1" target="_webapp">Turn off Mobile View</a>
 </li>
 <li>&nbsp;</li>
 <li>
  <a id="logoff_link" href="http://oursite.com/login.htm?logout=true" target="_webapp">Sign-Out</a>
 </li>
</ol>
```

I don't know what the issue is with these links as they are inconsistent across mobile devices.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Do they take you to the wrong page? Does nothing happen when you touch them? Please clarify.

Comment: Nothing happens. All of our icons with regular links work but these 2 do not????

Comment: is there any javascript code associated with those links? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Maybe show us the other icons, just to compare.

Comment: No, there are no errors associated with the links or JS. Confusing me big time.

Comment: It's tough to say, but I've had problems similar to this in the past... check your `z-index`!  Why not?  May help.  May not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution I found for this without having to make much change was to get rid of the target="_webapp" and using rel="external". This seemed to work the best.